# цикл кода html и стилей css

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Есть возможность создать цикл, что бы стили css применялись к данным из mysql. Вот пример кода:

```
<div id="topContainer"><? 
    do {
    echo $result->fetch_assoc;
    echo '<p>Name: <b>'.$rows['name'].'</b></p>';
    echo '<p>Year: <b>'.$rows['year'].'</b></p>';
        }
    while ($rows=$result->fetch_assoc());
    ?></p>
</div>
```

К данным которые выводятся первый раз, применяются стили css, а остальные уже без стилей, как можно сделать что бы и к ним тоже данный стиль применялся?

Comment: у вас на данных элементах нету классов, могли бы вы показать ваш  css который воздействует на эти элементы?

Comment: @sivik_xes     #topContainer {
     font-size: 1.3em;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 6px;
     background: #red;
      }

Comment: У вас после while  лишний закрывающий   </p>   попробуйте убрать

Comment: Ну и неправильно использовать `do-while` синтаксис. В данной ситуации лучше просто `while`.

Comment: получилось зациклить, но код php применяется только к одному стилю css <div id="topContainer"> а у меня есть ещё, т.е. у меня блок, в нем ещё блоки, и у них есть свои стили, разметка, вот она не работает, т.е. код php видит только какой то один блок. А у меня над <div id="topContainer">  есть ещё <div id="container">

Comment: так и зациклите тогда topContainer а не содержимое его

Comment: @LenovoID Не годится зацикливать блок с id. Внутри цикла уместен <div class="container">, например.

Comment: @Jasonartok Расскажите подробнее, сколько у вас блоков, и какие у них id, Черновая версия ответа - поставить всем блокам одинаковый класс и через него назначить нужные стили.